# How to pass custom allocator to std::basic_ostringstream in C++11?

Tags: c++11, stringstream, allocator, ostringstream

I want to use a custom allocator to allocate memory from a freelist for `std::basic_ostringstream`. Here is my custom allocator which I want to use:

```
template <class Tp>

    struct NAlloc {
        typedef Tp value_type;
        typedef value_type* pointer;
        typedef const value_type* const_pointer;
        typedef value_type& reference;
        typedef const value_type& const_reference;
        typedef std::size_t size_type;
        typedef std::ptrdiff_t difference_type;

        NAlloc() = default;
        template <class T> NAlloc(const NAlloc<T>&) {}
        Tp* allocate(std::size_t n) {
            n *= sizeof(Tp);
            memoryPool *memPool = memoryPool::GetInstance(10);//get memory pool instance
            std::cout << "allocating " << n << " bytes\n";
            return static_cast<Tp*>(memPool->allocate(n)); //get memory from pool
        }
        void deallocate(Tp* p, std::size_t n) {
            std::cout << "deallocating " << n*sizeof*p << " bytes\n";
            memoryPool *memPool = memoryPool::GetInstance(10);
            memPool->deallocate(static_cast<void*>(p));//return memory to pool
        }

   template<typename U>
   struct rebind {
    typedef NAlloc<U> other;
   };
```

Then, I use it like this:

```
typedef std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, NAlloc<char>> OstringStream;
```

****Problem:****

```
int main()
{
    OstringStream os; //Object creation
    os << " Hello, this is OstreamStream class with memory pool";  //here I am getting error
}
```

> Error: 'OstringStream {aka std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, NAlloc<char> >}' is not derived from 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>'

Comment: What's problem are you having with it?

Comment: If I do this, OstringStream os, os << "Hello" ;  std::cout <<os.str() .... I am getting error. OstringStream is not utilising std::basic_ostringstream functionality. Error: 'OstringStream {aka std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, NAlloc<char> >}' is not derived from 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>'

Comment: You need to [edit] the question to show your problem (rather than adding a comment).  Please write a [mcve] and include it in the body of the question.  Thanks.

Comment: You need to actually ask a question if you want help. Please put it in the question not in a comment.

Comment: Don't you have to overload the << operator in order to use it on your object?

Comment: I don't think so. I just want to use my custom allocator to handle memory allocation and deallocation. std::basic_ostringstream member function should work (without overloading). I suspect that allocation class for std::basic_ostringstream is not working correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `OstringStream` type is a typedef of [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), not of [`std::basic_ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream).  That is why you are getting the error from `operator<<`.  The left-hand operand must be an object derived from `std::basic_ostream`, exactly as the error message is saying.

`std::basic_ostream` itself does not use an allocator at all.  It uses [`std::basic_streambuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf) for all of its I/O.  For instance, [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) uses [`std::stringbuf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf), which uses the default `std::allocator`.

In C++11, `std::basic_ostringstream` has an optional `Allocator` template parameter, which it passes down to its internal `std::basic_stringbuf`.  So, you could write your `typedef` like this instead:

```
typedef std::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, NAlloc<char>> OstringStream;

int main()
{
    OstringStream os;
    os << " Hello, this is OstringStream with memory pool";
}
```

In earlier C++ versions, you would have to:

1. define a typedef of `std::basic_stringbuf` that uses your custom allocator instead of the default allocator.
2. construct a standard `std::ostream` object that uses an instance of your custom `stringbuf` type.

For example:

```
typedef std::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, NAlloc<char> > Stringbuf_NAlloc;

class OstringStream : public Stringbuf_NAlloc, public std::ostream
{
public:
    OstringStream() : Stringbuf_NAlloc(std::ios_base::out), std::ostream(this) {}
};

int main()
{
    OstringStream os;
    os << " Hello, this is OstringStream with memory pool";
}
```

In either case, know that the `os.str()` method will no longer return a standard `std::string`, which uses the default allocator.  It will return a `std::basic_string` that uses your custom allocator instead.  That will cause problems when trying to assign the return value of `os.str()` to a standard `std::string`, eg:

```
std::string s = os.str(); // error!
```

> error: conversion from ‘std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, NAlloc>::__string_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, NAlloc>}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ requested

So be aware of that.  The STL is not very flexible when it comes to mixing allocators, so if you use a custom allocator, you usually have to apply it to every type of data container you use from the STL.

Comment: thanks a lot!. I really like your explanation part. I am planning to use custom allocator for basic_string too.

Comment: This works fine for stateless allocators. The ostring_stream() ctor does not take an allocator object, but the stringbuf ctor does.  So your example for older C++ looks promising.